# How to print all columns after matching on key field

Tags: awk

How can I join all fields of each row from both files after matching on a key field? How to generalize this one-liner if the number of fields is unknown in f2?

```
f2:    
a 1 2    
b 3 4    
c 5 6   

f3:    
10 a x y z    
11 g x y z    
12 j x y z    

observed:    
a 10 x y z
a1 10 x y z

Desired:    
a 1 2 10 x y z
```

These are my best attempts but are incorrect:

> awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$2;next} ($2 in a) {print a[$2],$0}' f2.txt f3.txt > f4.txt
>
> awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$2$3;next} ($2 in a) {print a[$2],$0}' f2.txt f3.txt > f4.txt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  awk  'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$0;next} ($2 in a){print a[$2],$1,$3,$4,$5}' f2.txt f3.txt > f4.txt
```

save the whole as value and column1 as key, when read 2nd file, check column2 in array `a` or not, if it is, print `a[$2]` and the rest columns

A shorter way(the disadvantage of this command is there's one extra space between 10 and x):

```
awk  'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$0;next} ($2 in a){second=$2; $2="";print a[second],$0}' f2.txt f3.txt > f4.txt
```

replace $2 of 2nd file with empty string, and print the whole line `$0`

Answer (score 0):

@mxttgen31: try:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{Q=$2;$2="";A[Q]=$0;next} ($1 in A){print $0,A[$1]}'  f3  f2
```

Explanation of above command as follows:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{      ##### Checking condition FNR==NR here, where FNR and NR both denotes the number of line, 
                         only difference between FNR and NR is as we could read mutiple files from awk, 
                         value of FNR will be RESET on next file's start, where NR's value will be keep on increasing till 
                         it completes reading all the file. so this condition will be TRUE only when first Input_file(which is f3 here) will be TRUE.
Q=$2;              ##### Assigning second field's value to variable Q.
$2="";             ##### making second field's value to NULL now.
A[$2]=$0;          ##### Create an array named A whose index is $2 and value is current line.
next}              ##### putting next(awk's in-built keyword) which skips all next further statements and take the cursor again to starting.
($1 in A)          ##### Cursor will come here whenever second Input_file is being read, so here checking $1(first field) is present in array A then do following.
{print $0,A[$1]}   ##### print the current line($0) of current file named f2 and print array A's value whose index is $1 of current file f2.
' f3  f2           ##### Mentioning Input_files here.
```

Comment: your output is `a 1 2 a 10 x y z`, OP's desired output is `a 1 2 10 x y z
`

Answer (score 0):

if your files are sorted in the keys as in your example, `join` is the tool for this task

```
join -11 -22 f2.txt f3,txt
```